# Get Table Parent of an Element

Tags: javascript

I created dynamically a div with a class x in a table.  How can I with JavaScript catch the table parent of this div and give it a certain class?

Passing through the tr and td parent Node didn't worked.  Any ideas?

Comment: since your question has already been answered, I'll just comment that your script was proabably unaware of `<tbody>` between `<tr>` and `<table>` in the parentNode chain. Broswers insert it implicitly.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming that no libraries are involved.

```
function getNearestTableAncestor(htmlElementNode) {
    while (htmlElementNode) {
        htmlElementNode = htmlElementNode.parentNode;
        if (htmlElementNode.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'table') {
            return htmlElementNode;
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}

var table = getNearestTableAncestor(node);
if (table) {
    table.className += ' certain';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have jQuery, this is very easy. If your HTML is something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr><td><div class="mydiv">hi</div></td></tr>
</table>
```

Then you can say something like:

```
$('div.mydiv').closest('table').addClass('someclass');
```

The `closest` function goes up in the DOM tree until it reaches an element that matches the selector you give (in this case, `table`).

Answer (score 2):

This is a relatively old answer, but now we have [`.closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) which can traverse through elements until it finds the table:

```
var td = document.getElementById('myTdElement');
var table = td.closest('table');
if (table) {
    table.className += ' certain';
}
```

Compatibility:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the new div's already inserted into the DOM tree, you can use jquery:

```
$(div_node).parents('table')[0].addClass('certain_class');
```

Bare javascript can do similar things, but you'll have to write a loop to iterate up each .parentNode, test if it's a table, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery If your HTML is something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr><td><div class="divClass">Content</div></td></tr>
</table>
```

Then you can call parent table like:

> $('div.divClass').parent();

below code will give html of your table:

> alert($('div.divClass').parent().html());

You can use `$('div.divClass').parent();` as you want ...

Cheers!